# Facebook: Error Accessing App

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps, facebook-login

I have a very weird question. Hope someone can help me on this.
I have a Facebook login (PHP SDK) button on my website which is working fine ,means on clicking, asks for Facebook credentials in pop-up window, on success, registers the user and redirects to members page.
But sometimes, on clicking the login button, when Facebook pop-up window opens, it gives the following error:

```
Invalid API key
```

I checked the url it redirected to:
    https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?app_id=............5571&client_id=............5571&display=popup&domain=..............&response_type=token%2Csigned_request&scope=publish_stream&sdk=joey
Now I realised that the "app_id=............5571" is not supposed to be there. Because this is the App ID of my old Facebook app which I had deleted a week ago. And it is supposed to be my current App ID.
But on refreshing the page couple of times, when I click the login button again, it works fine, url includes the correct api_key and it successfully redirects to the members page.
I can't understand why sometimes it goes to incorrect url and then works fine after some time or on refreshing the login page?
Is there any app configuration I need to change???
Thanks in advance.

Comment: caching i suspect. Delete your browser's cache and report if the problem persists.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy, I tried that many times but there is no luck yet.
It seems to be something wrong while making redirect url.....let me know if you have some information regarding that as I am not much familiar with that. It is my first attempt to integrate website with Facebook.